# Как итерироваться по выражению?

Tags: python

```
INPUT: x = '(5+5)/[4+4]*{2*2}'  
OUTPUT: '(' , ' 5 ',  '+', '5' , ')' , '/ ', '[ ' , '4' , '+' , '4' , ' ] ' , '*' , '{' , '2' , '*' , '2' , '}'
```

Comment: `print(", ".join(map(repr, x)))`.

Answer (score 4):

```py
x = '(5+5)/[4+4]*{2*2}'
l = list(x)
print(l)
```

Результат:

```
['(', '5', '+', '5', ')', '/', '[', '4', '+', '4', ']', '*', '{', '2', '*', '2', '}']
```

Если нужно более тонко форматировать вывод, можно сделать что-то вроде такого:

```py
x = '(5+5)/[4+4]*{2*2}'
l = list(x)
print("'" + "' , '".join(l) + "'")
```

Результат:

```
'(' , '5' , '+' , '5' , ')' , '/' , '[' , '4' , '+' , '4' , ']' , '*' , '{' , '2' , '*' , '2' , '}'
```